# how many time i can keep the app processing in the applicationWillTerminate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How much time i can keep my app processing before terminating in the applicationWillTerminate delegate before the app stops by the OS itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Apple Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) an app has 5 seconds before it terminates.Search for "App Termination" on the page.